# Injeção de Depêndencia com Ninject C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, injeção-de-dependência, ninject

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que possui 4 camadas `Dominio, Infra, Servico e Web` Quando eu tendo acessar um rota por exemplo `Home/Index` ele fala que não existe nenhum construtor sem parâmetros, meu construtor esta assim :

```
public HomeController(IPessoaServico pessoaServico)
{
    this.pessoaServico = pessoaServico;
}
```

Eu tenho uma classe `NinjectWebCommon.cs` na pasta `App_Start`  com o seguinte código.

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Web.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(Web.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace Web.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;
    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;
    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;
    using Infra.Banco.Interface;
    using Infra.Banco;
    using Infra.Repositorio.Interface;
    using Infra.Repositorio;
    using Servico.Interface;
    using Servico;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon
        {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start()
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>

        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IDataBaseFactory>().To<DataBaseFactory>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();

            kernel.Bind<IPessoaRepositorio>().To<PessoaRepositorio>();
            kernel.Bind<IPessoaServico>().To<PessoaServico>();
    }
}
```

Coloquei apenas uma da entidades para exemplo, essa e a primeira vez que estou fazendo uma aplicação dessas e acho que estou deixando passar algo, caso alguém possa me ajudar, caso precise de mais informações e só falar.

EDIT : pesquisei um pouco e vi algumas pessoas indicando a instalação de 2 pacotes adicionais Ninject  MVC 5 e Ninject WEB.API , estou adicionando os 2 para fazer testes.

Comment: nesse código não tem o `IPessoaServico` registrada no método `RegisterServices`?

Comment: Tem sim, estão todas as entidades , coloquei apenas a primeira de exemplo. mas o restantes das entidades estão registradas da mesma forma inclusive a PessoaServico

Comment: Pra não haver confusão o código tem que bater com o outro código, evita o pessoal achar o que eu achei, vou elaborar um teste, qual é a versão do sua aplicação ASP.NET ?

Comment: Versão do MVC  = 5.2.3.0  estou usando o Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.5.2.3

Comment: Você está fazendo injeção em WebApi e também Web? Você precisa que funciona nos dois?

Comment: Futuramente eu irei fazer a Web api , mas agora é so web mesm, eu não adicionei o pacote web api apenas o MVC5

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47172/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-william-cezar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que a injeção de dependência com [**Ninject**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC5/3.2.0) funcione de maneira tanto para **Web MVC** e **WebApi** precisa da instalação de dois pacotes:

> [Install-Package Ninject.MVC5 -Version 3.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC5/3.2.0)

e

> [Install-Package Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver/)

após a instalação desses dois pacotes entre na pasta `App_Start` no arquivo `NinjectWebCommon.cs` e faça a adição de uma linha:

> `System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);`

no método `CreateKernel()` como layout exemplo logo abaixo:

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    try
    {
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
           new Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);

        RegisterServices(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }
    catch
    {
        kernel.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

um detalhe também é no `Global.asax` coloque em sua primeira linha `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
     ...
```

- [Ninject.MVC5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC5/3.2.0)
- [NinjectDependencyResolver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver/)
- [Ninject Dependency Resolver for Web Api](https://github.com/sethwebster/NinjectDependencyResolver)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, estava a bastante tempo tentando resolver este problema, obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Sim, eu entendo, tem que ver possibilidades e estudar nesse caso se não vai comprometer muito o desempenho. Talvez fazer um projeto pra cada e colocar os projetos separados vão dar mais trabalho na parte de manutenção e codificação. Tem que analisar mesmo se for pouca coisa WebApi eu colocaria tudo junto...

Comment: Muito obrigado você me ajudou muito, valeu mesmo.